# Use HellFire Compiler Daemon with Flex SDK 4.5.x

Tags: flex4.5, flashbuilder4

HellFire Compiler Daemon (HFCD) is significantly quicker than the default compiler used by Flash Builder, however it only seems to support Flex SDK 4.1.x.

Is there any way to use HFCD with Flex SDK 4.5.x?

Answer (score 0):

See http://hfcd.tenderapp.com/discussions/questions/11-flex-45

The Author of HFCD seems to have disappeared. We too are feeling the pain, supposedly there is a  way to integrate fcshd.py to get out of processing building to help speed up FlashBuilder.